# I want to create angular Chrome Extension Multi Page

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

So I want to create such type of extension but the problem after ng build is I can't open new page from the popup, because I have only 1 html file index.html. But I need to have another angular html file and open it from the popup in the new tab.

maybe someone know how to do it?

Here is My Structure

[image: Here is My Structure]

When i do ng build it creates dist folder:

[image: distFolder]

But the problem is when I try go to a new page it shows me this page

[image: the Page when I'm trying go to showAllData]

[image: app-routing.module.ts]

The question is how I can compile multiple html pages

Comment: Add `target=_blank` to the link.

Comment: @wOxxOm nope not works as it opens in a new tab but it can't be accessed (

Comment: @wOxxOm as I said, I am creating chrome extention and I want to click a button in the popup window and open a new tab with a new functionality but when I open the URL is changes and I need to have another HTML file to show it in the tab

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to open a new tab. Try configuring your router to use hash mode.